# Rails: replacing try with the Null Object Pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

In most of my applications, I have a `current_user` method. To avoid exceptions in cases like `current_user.name` where `current_user` is `nil`, rails provides the `try` method. The problem with this is that I need to remember to use `try` wherever `current_user` might be `nil`.

I want to use the Null Object pattern to remove this additional overhead.

```
class NullUser
  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    nil
  end
end

def current_user
  return NullUser.new unless UserSession.find
  @current_user ||= UserSession.find.user
end
```

This can replace `try` in some cases:

```
current_user.try(:first_name)     #=> nil
current_user.first_name           #=> nil
```

but fails with further chaining:

```
current_user.profiles.first.name    #=> undefined method...
```

---

I tried to return the null object:

```
class NullUser
  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    self.class.new
  end
end

current_user.try { |u| u.profiles.first.name }  #=> nil
current_user.profiles.first.name                #=> nil
```

but this would fail in other cases:

```
current_user.is_admin?            #=>  #<NullUser:0x96f4e98>
```

Is there a possible solution to this problem or do we all have to live with `try`?

Comment: can't understand why you seem to share the same pages between logged-in users and anonymous users. why isn't it properly split?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would stick with the `NullUser` but change its name to `GuestUser` to make things clearer. Additionally you should stub all important method from your User class, e.g.

```
class GuestUser
  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    nil
  end

  def is_admin?
    false
  end

  # maybe even fields:
  def name
    "Guest"
  end

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to chain methods on your `NullUser` instance, you need to have `method_missing` return `self` instead of `nil`. You attempt with returning `self.class.new` was close ...

[Avdi Grim explains how to implement a Null Object pattern in Ruby.](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/)