# What is the best practice for handling nil objects and properties?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have a `User` object, which has an `email` property, and I need the upper cased last letter of their `email`:

```
u = User.find(1)    
letter = u.email.upcase.last
```

If `u` or `email` is `nil` in this chain, then I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'blah' for nil:Nilclass`. I should be able to work around it in most cases, but sometimes, a `nil` gets where it shouldn't or its hard to contain. One way would be verbose:

```
u = User.find(1)
letter = nil
if u && u.email
 letter = u.email.upcase.last
end
```

But this gets annoying and hazardous in a view, or in a long chain of `a.bunch.of.properties.down.a.hierarchy`. I read about `try` method in Rails:

```
u = User.find(1)
letter = u.try(:email).try(:upcase).try(:last)
```

This is less verbose, but I feel icky writing all those tries. And once I put `try` in the chain, I have to use them all the way down. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like to use the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). [Avdi has a great post explaining this](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/), but the basic idea is you have a little class that can stand in for an object and respond reasonably to the messages you might pass the original object. I've found these are useful not only for avoiding `NoMethodError`s but also for setting default values/nice messages.

For instance, you could do:

```
class NilUser
  def email
    "(no email address)"
  end
end

u = User.find(1) || NilUser.new
u.email.upcase.last # => No errors!
```

Comment: This makes sense, but it doesn't feel any less verbose than using try.    I suppose its a pattern at least, and enforces better habits.

Comment: I have expanded on this personally. I added a `self.safe_find(id)` method to my User model that contains the `User.find(id) || NilUser.new` bit. That way my views are less cluttered with just `u = User.safe_find(1)`.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to update this thread with one more option: Ruby now (as of 2.3) gives us a safe navigation operator, the `&.` syntax.

So:

`u.email.upcase`

Would become:

`u.email&.upcase`

Similarly to Rail's `try` method, the whole chain will return `nil` if it encounters `NoMethodError` on a `nil`.

Comment: For the record, I like the null object pattern. If it feels too heavy-handed (e.g., I'm only worried about `nil` in one place) I'll use this instead.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this recently too, and have used it in a few locations now. Quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.find(1)
```

Will raise exception if user with id 1 not exist so you don't need to worry about nil here

```
u.email
```

If you have in your model

```
validates :email, presence: true
```

You don't need to worry about nil because User without email cant be in database

But I think you are asking about general way of handling nils in ruby code. Lately I'm using Null Object pattern

http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/20907555103/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object

[Rails: replacing try with the Null Object Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077115/rails-replacing-try-with-the-null-object-pattern)

https://github.com/martinciu/nullobject

Comment: Yes, it was a contrived example for the purposes of the question - not a real one. I was asking about the pattern.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also map the result of find

```
[User.find(1)].map{|u| (u != nil ? u.mail : "no mail")}[0]
```