# .each method in Ruby on Rails if nothing is in the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a product page that has `<% @packs['sample-pack'].each do |pack| %>` and works when there is at least one product in the table. When the table is empty (has no products) there is an error with the `.each` method.

I'm fairly certain that the table being empty in the DB is causing this and was wondering if there was a proper way of handling `.each` "if" there is something there? (whether the table is empty or not)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check out the links in the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469335/what-is-the-best-practice-for-handling-nil-objects-and-properties Or you can just use `if/else` or `try`. There are a lot of ways to handle it, but you'll have to decide how you want to go about it

Comment: If you're getting a NoMethodError then the `@packs` hash doesn't have a `'sample-pack'` key so you're saying `nil.each`. So `<% if @packs['sample-pack'] %>` and `<% @packs['sample-pack'].to_a.each do |pack| %>` are your friends.

Comment: @muistooshort I am, actually. Would turning the items in the table into an array like you suggested have any impact on load speed or functionality? The packs in the index lead to their respective /show view

Comment: I would also like to advise you to first prepare the list of  objects to render in the view in an service object and then pass them to the view in an instance variable.

Comment: You should probably rethink how you're populating `@packs['sample-pack']`, and ensure that in the case where there are no products, the value is `[]` not `nil`. You shouldn't have to check for `nil` before doing an `each`, you should just ensure that the subject is always an array of 0 or more items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `&` that performs a nil-check before call right side function/attribute. Like `@packs['sample-pack']&.each`

A good pratice is extract `@packs['sample-pack']` to an variable or a controller method like [helper_method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a method on an object that does not exist.

A good practice is to use a Null Object pattern. Basically, you would implement an object that responds to methods your real objects respond to. For example:

```
class GueranteedPack
  def self.find(id) # this could be any method you need
    Pack.find(id) || MissingPack.new
  end
end

class MissingPack
  def find # same here
    'no pack'
  end
end
```

And finally:

```
@packs = GuarantedPack.find(...)
@packs.each do |pack|
```

The things is that you need an object that implements the same API as your real object. This way, you avoid getting nil values and having to imlement conditions in your view.

This code is better to read and does not clutter your view with additional logic, which does not belong there.

Obiously you could do:

```
if @packs['sample-pack'].any?
  @packs.each do |pack|
  ...
  end
end
```

but putting logic into views is not considered a good practice and you should avaiod that.
I recommend to watch this video - Sandi Metz explaining Null Object pattern: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMPfEXIlTVE
I hope it makes sense to you.